# photoswipe.js blank rendering in codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, photoswipe

I'm using photoswipe a jquery gallery plugin. I got no error in the console. I'd included all the required js and css. Not sure why is it blank.

http://codepen.io/eldyvoon/pen/BLWWbW

```
$(document).on('click','.album_item',function(){

          var photosIndex = $(this).closest('.box_album_item').index() - 2;
          console.log(photosIndex)

          var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];

          var gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, pswpAlbum_Items);
          gallery.init();

          gallery.goTo(photosIndex);

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment `display: none` to show album

```
#album_item{
    margin: 0 -1px 0 -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    //display: none;
    margin-top: 31px;
}
```